# For loop doesn't carry out all funtions

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm currently trying to run this for loop -

```
for i in [R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6]:
    i = i[i.route == int(m)]
    i['stop'] = i['stop'].astype(str)
    i['route_sequence'] = i.stop.str[0:3]
    i = i[i["time2"] != 0]
    i['sequence'] = np.roll(i['route_sequence'], 1)
    i['Seconds'] = pd.to_numeric(i['Seconds'], errors='coerce')
    i_Unique = i['route_sequence'].unique()
```

However, once it gets past the first line of the code (i = i[i.route == int(m)]) it doesn't carry out any of the remaining tasks. It's not giving me any errors either so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Edit -

The m in the for loop is defined here

```
for m in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]:
    exec('{} = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("R_" + m + ".csv"))'.format("R" + m))
```

Comment: what is m? It is not defined in your loop. I think possibly you mean `for m in [r1, r2] etc`

Comment: @WoodyPride m is defined in a previous loop. I've edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Once you've gone throught he first loop, `m` will be `"6"`. Is that the value you want it to be when in the `for i in [...]:` loop?

Comment: In order to diagnose this issue you would need to post some data upon which to test it. If there is no error then this is likely caused by some naming issue. I would start by renaming your `i` inside the loop, as you are also using `i` as your iterator which is confusing at best and possibly causing you issues